# Cakephp AppView function from view

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How do you call a function that you wrote in the AppView in another view? Eg the index view?

```
<?php
/**
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link      http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @since     3.0.0
 * @license   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */
namespace App\View;

use Cake\View\View;

/**
 * Application View
 *
 * Your application’s default view class
 *
 * @link http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#the-app-view
 */
class AppView extends View
{       

    public function initialize(){
    }       

    public function printNavSidebar(){
        echo '<nav class="large-1 medium-2 columns" id="actions-sidebar">';
    }


}
```

How do i call the function printNavSidebar() in my index view?

Comment: @BadHorsie I guess the OP wanted to refer to view _templates_, not just view classes.

Comment: Why would you post on this question when i answered it myself and then tell me to learn about OOP? Kinda rude.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops found it. In a template `$this` is an instance of the view class so:

```
$this->printNavSidebar();
```